# Convert .mkv to .mp4

Tags: video, mp4, mkv

I am trying to convert .mkv to .mp4
Following is the my terminal. I get an error saying

> Cannot find H264 start code. Error importing video.h264: BitStream Not
>   Compliant

```
gayan@GayanF:~/Videos/converted$ mkvmerge --identify file.mkv
File 'file.mkv': container: Matroska
Track ID 0: video (VP9)
Track ID 1: audio (AAC)
Global tags: 1 entry
Tags for track ID 0: 2 entries
Tags for track ID 1: 4 entries

gayan@GayanF:~/Videos/converted$ mkvextract tracks file.mkv 0:video.h264 1:audio.ac3
Extracting track 0 with the CodecID 'V_VP9' to the file 'video.h264'. Container format: IVF
Extracting track 1 with the CodecID 'A_AAC' to the file 'audio.ac3'. Container format: raw AAC file with ADTS headers
Progress: 100%
gayan@GayanF:~/Videos/converted$ MP4Box -fps 24 -add video.h264 -add audio.ac3 video.mp4
Cannot find H264 start code
Error importing video.h264: BitStream Not Compliant
```

Comment: Would you be happy to use FFmpeg rather than your current methods? If so something like the following should suffice: `ffmpeg -i file.mkv -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy video.mp4`

Comment: @andrew.46 thank you so much. I tried ffmpeg earlier and failed to do that. But with your command it was successfull. Many thanks to you. You saved my time. Thank you mate!!!!

Comment: Hi @andrew.46 , I am trying to convert another .mkv to .mp4. But it gives an error saying "[mp4 @ 0x183f980] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x183f980] Could not find tag for codec opus in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container"

Comment: Best for your second file that you add the details to your original question. Show the codecs in the second file by running the command `ffmpeg -i filename` where 'filename' is changed to the actual filename of your input file. If we can reach a happy resolution on this file as well I will make a formal 'answer' below! (My suspicion is that your second file has a different audio codec and this is easily fixed...)

Comment: In 2nd case you're trying to use opus audio in .mp4.  By default that's not allowed though at least here can be done by adding `-strict -2` option to ffmpeg command.  Simple ex. here - `ffmpeg -i  /home/doug/Videos/whatever.mkv -c: copy  -strict -2   /home/doug/Videos/whatever.mp4`

Comment: If using opus in .mp4 doesn't work out or work out well then you'd need to re-encode audio to aac